# Serializing and de-serializing Clojure code as EDN

Tags: clojure, edn

I'm trying to use a standard serialization for Clojure code, one that will ignore white spaces, comments etc.  I was thinking of using [EDN](https://github.com/edn-format/edn) for that.

According to the what I read, the standard way to serialize s-expressions to EDN is through `pr-str`, which seems to work nicely with most of Clojure's constructs.  However, this seems not to work that well for code containing regular expressions (using the hash-string reader macro, like `#"\d+"`).

```
user=> (pr-str '#"\d")
"#\"\\d\""

user=> (edn/read-string (pr-str '#"\d"))

RuntimeException No dispatch macro for: "  Clojure.lang.Util.runtimeException (Util.java:221)
```

I'm using Clojure 1.8.0.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
Thanks for your answers and comments.  The reason I wanted to use EDN to begin with was that I want to handle untrusted code.

The idea is that I want to read this code (any syntactically-valid Clojure code), and then pass it through some special-purpose static analysis to make sure it complies with a specific subset of Clojure that I consider "safe", and only if it complies I would consider it safe to execute this code.  For this reason I want to avoid `load-file`, which loads the file right away, and also possibly `read-string`, due to [these warnings](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/read-string) regarding it.

Comment: My _guess_ here is, that the focus for EDN is to store data, not "code". You could use the regular `read-string` (with it's pitfalls) instead. If it helps a proper answer: it is disabled here: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blame/master/src/jvm/clojure/lang/EdnReader.java#L53

Comment: Why don't you just save Clojure code in to a .clj file and load it using Clojure?

Comment: See my edit regarding `read-string` and `load-file`.

Answer (score 1):

Clojure is a superset of EDN, so not all Clojure features are supported. The output of `pr-str` is a valid Clojure program that has been escaped to fit in a `String`. The `RuntimeException` is complaining about the first escaped `"`, which is not supported by the EDN `#` reader macro.

```
(clojure.core/read-string (pr-str #"\d")) ;=> #"\d"
```